# Different branches has one readme.md in same repository

Tags: github, warnings, conflict, readme

Is possible to stop showing warning in **github** for different branches has same name in README.md file.

The warning asking for compare and pull request, because those branches conflict in README.md file. Yeay, my purpose is having different README in each branches.

Branches tree

```
main (branch)
|--README.md
lesson-1 (branch)
|--README.md
```

Comment: Where do you see warnings?

Comment: hmm.. i check it back in my github project repository the warning request is gone. =) lol